# Using wp_register_style to load CSS in footer?

Tags: footer, wp-register-script, wp-register-style

I realise you can enqueue JS in the footer using `wp_register_script` as there is a `$in_footer` parameter for doing so. However, there isn't one for `wp_register_style` it seems.

Is there a way to enqueue CSS in the footer in the same way, or do I have to manually hardcode the file path in my footer.php file?

Comment: Any reason you need to do this?

Comment: Yes. Stylesheets should be added to header.

Comment: `<style>` tag anywhere outside `<head>` is invalid (if not `scoped`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technically styles should only be output in head and outputting them elsewhere is invalid HTML (browsers are however very lax about it and don't care much).

So in best interest of standards WordPress wouldn't do something like that. Right? Right!?

It does without bit of remorse actually. There is [`print_late_styles()`](http://queryposts.com/function/print_late_styles/) function, running in footer that will output any queued styles that hadn't appeared in the header.

So while there is no explicit way to enqueue style for footer (like for scripts), simply adding them into queue after header had passed will make them appear there.

Still not too good of an idea, but it does work.

Comment: Thanks for the clear explanation (and to everyone else for their input). My only reason for considering it was to try and speed things up on the page, but obviously if it's bad practice I'll scrap the idea!

Comment: It is worth mentioning here that Google Pagespeed makes recommendations to only load critical "above the fold" CSS in the header, because CSS in the header is render-blocking. Then after the above the fold content has loaded, you can load the rest of your styles. Read more here: https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/OptimizeCSSDelivery

Comment: @MattKeys I wouldn't use grossly invalid HTML because Google said to, personal opinion.

Comment: This could probably use an update, as the [spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/html52/links.html#link-type-stylesheet) now says that using `rel="stylesheet"` in the `body` is ok.